# Forwarding the xml without parsing in a rest service using Spring MVC

Tags: xml, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to add a middle layer rest service which infact gets an xml by calling another restservice . I would like to send same xml as is as output of my middle layer service. I dont want to parse the xml, is there any way? I am using Spring3 MVC to develop this middle layer rest service.Actually I wanted to forward the xml without parsing. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook up the InputStream you get from your other REST service to your OutputStream:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forward/")
public void foo(HttpServletResponse response)  {
  InputStream in = //... get inputstream from your other REST service
  IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
}
```